# flexible box layout OR grid layout OR multiple column

Tags: html, css

I do not know what I need to use to create the **fundation** of my website. Tipically, I want a design structure having **3 columns** in the main content. (column 1 = navigation panel, column 2 = central for content, column 3 = advert panel).

What ares the best practises (using CSS3 if possible) to realize this design ? I hesite between the flexible box layout OR grid layout OR multiple column method. (I do not understand what is the most adapted to my case, in order to have a simple, flexible and less display bugged solution). I also want my website to fill as well as possible the screen (using the more available space).

Do I need to define a screen resolution, or all is possible with % ?

Tkx,

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?  It all gets significantly simpler if you don't worry about any version of IE before 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing structure, I usually do something like the following (psuedo-code):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="column" id="left">
    <div class="column" id="middle">
    <div class="column" id="right">
```

The `wrapper` could be fixed width or fluid.  I usually fix width this and center it on the page using `margin: 0 auto` in the CSS.

The `left`, `middle`, `right` are for the columns.  I would set `display: inline-block` in a class name called `column` and control each individual column size using it's `id` selector in the CSS.

I like the flexible box layout though as this is a good fit for this problem but I've yet to play much with it. If I'm not mistaken, I don't think it's supported in every browser as of yet but it might be worth a shot.

As far as dealing with different screen sizes, media queries in CSS are the way to go. There are numerous resources and step-by-step guides around the web that should get you up and going with this in no time.  Hope this helps.